How to mock an @InjectValue property from a test
I have a class like the following:
export class TestClient {
    @InjectValue("VALUE_A")
    private valueA: string;

    public constructor(accessToken: string) {
        const object = {
            host: this.valueA
        };
    }
}

How can I mock, inject, pass a value to valueA from the Jest test file?
it("Should instantiate the client", () => {
    const client = new TestClient("");
    expect(client).toBeInstanceOf(TestClient);
});


What's actually providing InjectValue? You should probably be setting up the container with a valid definition to inject, the details will depend what's in use.

If you're using something like this then why not rebind the constant within the test?

@apokryfos you are right!
Adding Container.bindName("VALUE_A").to(value); into the test did the trick and solved my problem.
